# Trigger a click on a HTML element (in dart)

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm trying to trigger a click on html element (in dart).

In other words, how can I execute the function that is normally executed when the element is clicked ?

Here is an example:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  querySelector("#first").onClick.listen((e) {
    r() => new Random().nextInt(256);
    querySelector("#first").style.color =
      "rgb(${r()},${r()},${r()})";
  });

  querySelector("#second").onClick.listen((e) {
    // pretend the first paragraph is clicked
  });  
}
```

see also: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/456f1ec945536caf310c

Answer (score 5):

This should work to produce a mouse event

```
querySelector("#second").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(...))
```